# restriction on combination of two generics

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in TypeScript to express "You can pass in any two objects, as long as their combination satisfies type X"?

So, if I have the following function:

```
function myFunction(options: {x: number, y: string}){
}
```

And then, I have a function, that wants to call this function using an combination of two objects:

```
function callMyFunction<A,B>(a:A,b:B){
    myFunction({...a,...b})
}
```

And then it would compile if I did one of the following:

```
callMyFunction({},{x:1,y:"hello"})
callMyFunction({x:1},{y:"hello"})
callMyFunction({x:1,y:"hello"},{})
```

But would not compile if I did for example:

```
callMyFunction({x:1},{}) //y missing
callMyFunction({},{y:"hello"}) //x missing
callMyFunction({},{}) //x and y missing
```

I know that it's possible to restrict a generic type using `extends`. But is there a way to restrict the combination of two generic types? I imagine something like this:

```
function callMyFunction<A,B, A&B extends {x:number,y:string}>(a:A,b:B){
    myFunction({...a,...b})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in TypeScript to express "You can pass in any two objects, as long as their combination satisfies type X"?

This is a terrific question! And the answer is YES.

Here is an approach [(with a playground link)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3lAHgFxQoCuAtgEYQBOA3FCMWsDQigOZQC+dAUADNSKAMaJUUciABiwschQAKJPAVpiccegCUubn0FytUEQEMANuYCyMowoA8AQQA0UAEIA+RXyhQAdAEA2qaulAC6xI5QAGTuUBD4wBAoACYYmmpQAPxQgS7uYVDEKBAAbrR8ujg+JqgsUCpaGNh4AX4h-gGUPPy+UrKiWorKqnVQphjCANYoSADuKLoTsKM6-Pp8APQAVNs+21AAKgAWEGjQFua15GAI5hB++5t8ZpY2A-KoijjcrnhEUAAjK4mFAAESnSxIME8bT8V7WWyDBTfAjEQE8P6MYgQiBQmHcOEvS7vOxff7okE4yHmaGYvREra7fZQRw0DgUZLABoCKCgSBQAAGAHJAhSSBRqPR6T8wsLBVAEBhZtyJmgEBwUKZKPcWcAkFAwKYaKZyBAkjQeXzwNARSVyjR5X5gGhFAAmADMABYAKzaJ7Et5Iz5KcUY34M-hMvZQA5sjlmlDcpC8-m20U-LGglhsTgMbhyhVKkhIVVodWa7W62N8g1Gk1mi1WtNC4X22hOl3u71+gMI0nI8kRvCg3H42FRnYxuPszlJ5s21ti4cF+WK5Wl8bljVanUQPV142m820BcCu1lDuC52uz2+-2x5794NDTORvhAA). The approach uses a heady mix of TypeScript and JavaScript features. It uses generics, rest `...` parameters, array destructuring, conditional types, the `never` type, and a tuple type. It also tells the compiler that "we know more than it does" by using the `as unknown as Options` technique.

```
type Options = { x: number; y: string };
function myFunction(options: Options) {}

function callMyFunction<A, B>(
  ...[a, b]: A & B extends Options ? [A, B] : never
) {
  const options = { ...a, ...b };
  myFunction((options as unknown) as Options);
}
```

In `callMyFunction`, if the intersection of types `A` and `B` satisfies the type `Options`, then the two `...` rest parameters will be of type `A` and `B`. If the intersection does not satisfy the type `Options`, then the rest parameters are of type `never`, which in turn tells the type checker to complain.

The result is that these all pass type checking...

```
callMyFunction({}, { x: 1, y: "hello" });
callMyFunction({ x: 1 }, { y: "hello" });
callMyFunction({ x: 1, y: "hello" }, {});
```

...and that none of these pass type checking.

```
/**
 * Argument of type `'[{ x: number; }, {}]'` is not assignable
 * to parameter of type `'never'`.ts(2345)
 */
callMyFunction({ x: 1 }, {});

/**
 * Argument of type `'[{}, { y: string; }]'` is not assignable
 * to parameter of type `'never'`.ts(2345)
 */
callMyFunction({}, { y: "hello" });

/**
 * Argument of type `'[{}, {}]'` is not assignable
 * to parameter of type `'never'`.ts(2345)
 */
callMyFunction({}, {});
```

The resultant error messages could use improvement. As is, the error messages do not tell developers much about the required arguments. Someone with more TypeScript knowledge than I have can chime in about whether we can improve the error message or not.

Comment: That's... that's impressive! :D But the error message would indeed make this rather unpractical. I'm courious if there are other takes on this.

Comment: @VanCoding I think similarly to you. It isn't quite the answer I would be wanting to implement in production code. It seems both too opaque and too difficult to read.